# Creating an array then selecting based on it

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I need a linq call to return a list of floor id's in an array format so that I am able to use it to do a Contains call to return all the related data.

I can't get linq to return an array of floors.

```
var myFloors = 
(from f in db.Floor
where f.BuildingId == txBuildingId
select new { f.FloorId }).ToArray();
```

Then, I am having trouble selecting based on that Array.

```
var model =
(from r in db.Room
where myFloors.Contains(r.FloorId) 
select new
{
    label = r.Name,
    value = r.RoomId
});
```

I could do this easily in SQL with a string and by using the IN clause. I am fairly new to LINQ and am having alot of trouble with this. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to have anonymous type in here, you can select floorId directly:

```
var myFloors = 
(from f in db.Floor
where f.BuildingId == txBuildingId
select f.FloorId);
```

For more readable, I prefer using lambda style:

```
var myFloors = db.Floor.Where(f => f.BuildingId == txBuildingId)
                       .Select(f => f.FloorId);
```

So:

```
var model = db.Room.Where(r => myFloors.Contains(r.FloorId))
                   .Select(r => new {
                        label = r.Name,
                        value = r.RoomId    
                    });
```

Comment: He asked for an array, so you may want to add .ToArray() at the end of your statements.

Comment: @Namfuak: With the purpore of using in the second query, no need to use `ToArray` at the end

Comment: I just wanted to figure this out as it will come in handy for other things I have to do in the future. But yes it is not completly nessecary. Thanks for help.

Comment: I'm still having trouble with this. The first query returns an array, but the second myFloors.Contains(r.FloorId) breaks the query every time.

Comment: @TrentStewart: What exception you have?

Comment: I am getting in the model: {System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery<<>f__AnonymousType10<string,int>>}

Comment: Ok it seems to be working if I use lambda style and not comprehention syntzx for some weird reason. Oh well it should do. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

If you have `Floor` reference defined in `Room`, you can merge the 2 Linq queries to one, which is more efficient in terms of performance.

```
db.Room.Where(x=>x.Floor.BuildingId == txBuildingId).Select(r => new {
    label = r.Name,
    value = r.RoomId
})
```